# $pq\equiv 1\pmod 4$, how to find $p,q\bmod 4$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Somebody asked me a question, I have no idea about it, the question is:

> If a positive integer $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$ is the product of two primes, (denotes $n=pq,$ such as a *RSA* number) but we don't know what $p,q$ is, can we find whether $p,q\equiv 1\pmod 4$ or $p,q\equiv -1\pmod 4$ quickly?

**Edit:** To make this problem clearer, I'd like to illustrate this with an example:

Given $n=54106525115786488721104110650095154684919808365060517563123199931159\\
571762703975072565387621847347234678280888429084887681391085492532589162\\
3649321540843857479706239369353295580392388377=pq,$

Can you find $p\pmod 4$ and $q\pmod 4$ in less than one hour by computer?

Comment: Now that I read more carefully the question: both primes have the same residue modulo $\;4\;$ , as can be easily checked...and they both are, of course, odd.

Comment: @TMM That answers precisely nothing. She's asking if there's some way to determine quickly from the number $n$ whether the factors are 1 or 3 mod 4, where quickly means compared to factoring. She knows both are possible.

Comment: Just to show the fact that both $p$ and $q$ should have the same residue modulo $4$:
Since $p$ and $q$ are primes, here are $4$ possibilities:
$1)p \equiv 1\pmod 4$ and $q\equiv 1\pmod 4$
$2)p \equiv -1\pmod 4$ and $q\equiv 1\pmod 4$
$3)p \equiv 1\pmod 4$ and $q\equiv -1\pmod 4$
$4)p \equiv -1\pmod 4$ and $q\equiv -1\pmod 4$
Having $ pq \equiv 1\pmod 4$,By multiplication we can conclude cases $2$ and $3$ can't be correct. So our assumption is correct.

Comment: @TBrendle Yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: This seems like a research-level question, so maybe you will have better luck at MathOverflow. Unless I'm missing something, finding $p,q \bmod 4$ is non-trivial, in which case a possible approach to prove that it is difficult would be to show that: if you can find $\alpha \in \{1,3\}$ in $p = 4p' + \alpha$ and $q = 4q' + \alpha$, then you can somehow reduce factoring $N = pq$ to factoring something like $N' = p'q'$. That would imply that being able to find $\alpha$ for arbitrary $p,q$ would give you a fast algorithm to factor $N$, which is not very likely.

Answer (score 0):

$p,q\equiv 1\pmod 4$ if and only if the congruency $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{pq}, x\in\mathbb Z$ is solvable.

Because of the first supplement to quadratic reciprocity, this holds true for the congruencies $$x_1^2\equiv -1\pmod p\\x_2^2\equiv -1\pmod q$$ separately. Since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are only defined up to a multiple of p and q respectively, a simultaneous solution is possible whenever both congruencies are solvable (by the chinese remainder theorem).

Comment: And have you a fast way to determine that?

Comment: Even by naively checking all numbers smaller pq, the complexity should still remain polynomial, no?

Comment: In these matters, polynomial usually refers to the length of the number (digits, bits), which is proportional to the logarithm of $pq$. If polynomial referred to the value, simple trial division would be sublinear.

Comment: I don't know much about computational matters and such. It still seems to me that checking for congruence should not take as long as factorization. I would have posted my answer as a comment, had I the reputation to do so. Just thought that it might help.